# Storing dictionary in session state good or bad?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dictionary, session-variables, session-state

So I have a webpage, that has about 30 - 40 different controls (mainly radio buttons and checkboxes) that users can select as part of an IT request for new equipment. I am storing all of this data in  a dictionary, that I then pass onto a database.

Also on this page is a button called 'Next', that when clicked goes to a different page that displays a crystal report in the browser of what they chose on the previous page.  This allows them print the report, or save it or submit onto HR.

On the report page is the "previous" button,  that when clicked takes them back to the page where they selected all the different options.

**My issue is:** When I click the previous button, the selections of the different controls is lost.  So I was thinking about adding my dictionary to a session variable, so that upon a 'Previous' click, I could retain that data and set the controls to what they had chosen.

Is this a good idea? Why or why not?

Is there some other way to retain the control data that you would suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using the Session to save this kind of info.

Drawbacks:

1. Opening multiple forms not possible;
2. Values in dictionary are not typed.

Solutions:

1. Save it in the database already, having status `incomplete` (use `SessionId` for example for the retrieval);
2. Store the info in the `ViewState` (it travels with the page);
3. Use a `class` and store it in the `Session`.